# How can I register Oracle's JDBC driver in Neo4j?

Tags: oracle, neo4j

I'd like to import data from Oracle into Neo4j. As the first step I'm trying to register Oracle's JDBC driver using the statement below:

```
CALL apoc.load.driver("oracle.jdbc");
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.driver`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load driver class oracle.jdbc oracle.jdbc
```

I have put the Oracle's JDBC jar files (downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html)) in the plugin folder and restarted the server. The "oracle.jdbc" name is used because of the recommendation in [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#02_16). The plugin folder I've used is the correct one, since I am able to invoke other Apoc calls.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please paste the full stacktrace from `debug.log` (or `neo4j.log`) ?

Comment: It doesn't include any errors. It just contains messages which look like description of available Apoc procedures. such as:

"APOC: apoc.warmup.Warmup declares procedure apoc.warmup.run writes false desc apoc.warmup.run() - quickly loads all nodes and rels into memory by skipping one page at a time"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no driver called `oracle.jdbc` the actual driver class is `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` - so you should try to load that class. Also, library(JAR file) that contains driver class should be in your classpath.
So following should help:

```
CALL apoc.load.driver("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

Comment: Thanks. Absolutely correct. As I mentioned in my explanation, I used the phrase "oracle.jdbc" according to Oracle's documentation.